# JOptionPane throwing error when cancelled

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, joptionpane

Currently having an issue where I am popping a message dialog up to prompt the user to enter a string. I have a check for the name being empty which works properly if they hit the "ok" button however if the user hits the cancel button (whether they input anything into the textbox or not) then I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at cc.nisc.mapping.mappingadvsearch.ResultsPopupMenu$1.doActionPerformed(ResultsPopupMenu.java:98)
at cc.nisc.gui.action.NiscAction.actionPerformed(NiscAction.java:225)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
```

The relevant code is :

```
public final ResultsMenuAction createLayerAction = new ResultsMenuAction("uiCreateLayer") {
    @Override
    protected void doActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            String queryName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(WinMgr.getInstance().getSelectedNavigator(),
                                                           "Enter a name for your exported query layer",
                                                           "Enter Query Name",
                                                           JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (queryName.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(WinMgr.getInstance().getSelectedNavigator(),
                                              "Please enter a name for your query",
                                              "Empty name",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
            ....
            ....
```

How can I check to see if the cancel button has been clicked in order to return instead of raising the error?

Comment: `queryName` is most likely null and not an empty string. In fact when you cancel the dialog you select _nothing_ (in most cases the meaning of _null_).

Comment: Replace queryName.isEmpty() by string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryName)

Comment: I tried using "if (queryName.isEmpty() || queryName == null) {" with no success. I will try the two suggestions you two have made

Comment: Test for null first...

Comment: Checking for null first worked! Why would it ever matter if I do of(A || B) or if(B || A) ?

Comment: See my answer below. In fact `A|B` and  `A||B` are different in Java.

Comment: edited comment, i was in fact using ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JavaDoc on `JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog()` which is called by the method you're using:

> Returns:
>   user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

Thus `null` would indicate the input being cancelled.

To check for null or empty input, you'd first check the for null and then for empty, since calling `isEmpty()` on null will result in an NPE.

Keep in mind that `||` is the short circuit *or* operator, i.e. it will evaluate expressions from left to right and stop whenever a condition becomes true. Thus `if( queryName == null || queryName.isEmpty() )` won't throw a NPE because if `queryName` is null the condition is true and `isEmpty()` is never called.

In contrast a single pipe `|` isn't a short circuit operator, i.e. both expressions are evaluated regardless of whether the left is already true. Thus `queryName == null | queryName.isEmpty()` might still throw a NPE.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having  `if (queryName.isEmpty()) {`, try changing that line to this:

```
 if (queryName == null || queryName.isEmpty()) {
```

The reason you are most likely getting an error is because `queryName` is most likely null. So attempting to call `isEmpty()` on a null object will give you a null pointer exception.